# ansible sudo bypass to local host

Tags: ansible, sudo

I am currently running the ansible playbook with a user called ansible on the controller machine having less privileges . The requirement is to mount a nfs share on this same controller machine. Here is my code snippet and the error I face. Is there anyway I can bypass the "sudo incorrect password error "

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    FLSYSTEM: 'abc.xyz.com:/folder1'
    MOUNTPOINT: '/folder1'
  become: yes
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  #==================================================================
  - name: mount share
    mount:
      src: '{{ FLSYSTEM }}'
      path: '{{ MOUNTPOINT }}'
      fstype: nfs
      opts: rw,sync
      state: mounted
```

I run into the error

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "error occurred on host : sudo password is incorrect"
```

Comment: are you executing the playbook with `--ask-become-pass` ? how are you providing the password for sudo?

Comment: The best way to stop a `password is incorrect` message is usually to provide a correct password or eventually (since we are talking about `sudo`) to allow the user to [gain privilege without a password](https://linuxhandbook.com/sudo-without-password/). Note that you may face other errors once you get it right if you did not setup your host/target correctly for [privilege escalation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_privilege_escalation.html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what I have done as a solution, since maintaining the password for this user was not an option I had. I made changed to the sudoers file to allow the ansible user to mount the nfs

ansible ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/mount

This is what my code looks like now

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    MOUNTPOINT: "/folder1"
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
#==================================================================
  - name: Check whether /folder1 is mounted
    shell: |
             df -h | grep {{ MOUNTPOINT }} |
             awk 'END{
                 if (NR ==0)
                 {
                  print "mount"
                 }
                 else
                 {if ( NR ==1 )
                 {
                    print "Ok"
                 }
                 else
                 {
                 print "Error"
                 }}
                 }'
    register: mountpt
    ignore_errors: true
    changed_when: false
  - debug: msg="{{mountpt.stdout}}"
#==================================================================
  - name: mount /folder1
    shell: |
              sudo mount {{ MOUNTPOINT }}
    register: mntpt
    when: "'mount' in mountpt.stdout"
    changed_when: false
```